# Server, Remote Login, SSH?

Tags: command-line, networking, server, ssh, vnc

Two Things. I'm trying to setup multiple server applications on Ubuntu With Terminal using **SSH**.

1. I need to be able to use some form of login to the applications VNC, (having trouble with) SSH GREAT, but even if I close the connection I cannot connect back to the server Terminal application. So how do I access the Terminals from a re-login with SSH? (or any other suggestions)
2. How do I run multiple terminals on a single SSH connection?

In conclusion, I want to use SSH (or some other thing) to connect to multiple Terminal applications (already running) to have Console access for the servers or file management.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use a terminal multiplexer.

A good one to use that's easy to learn is `screen`. You can get it by:

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

To create a new `screen` session:

```
screen -S somename
```

This will spawn a new session with your default shell. To detach, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> followed by <kbd>d</kbd>.

To list current `screen` sessions:

```
screen -ls
```

To re-attach to a detached session:

```
screen -r somename
```

To create a "multi-user" screen session so that more than one person can view and type in the session:

```
screen -m -S shared
```

To join a multi-user session:

```
screen -X shared
```

To terminate a screen a session, you can either:

```
kill PID (found with screen -ls)
```

or while the screen is attached <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>

Comment: Does Screen allow you to run multiple Terminals disconnect from them, and come back and access all of them again?           Thanks, Landon

Comment: That's exactly what it is designed for! Create a screen session, start working, detach, log-off, log back in, reattach, continue working.

Comment: Great, I'll try that.

Comment: Remember, if this answer helped you, you can click the grey "checkmark" next to this answer to make it green, meaning "Yes! This solved my problem!"